# How to pass data into useState using useEffect - next.js ( swr hook for fetching and cache )

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to pass data into my useState, the problem is that, useEffect hasn't been able to to perform this operation too well...

This is what i have

```
const PublicationsHome = ({ data: allPubs }) => {
  // All pubs

  const { data: Publications }: thePublication = useSWR(
    `${process.env.URL}/api/publication`,
    {
      initialData: allPubs,
      revalidateOnFocus: false
    }
  );

  const [pubRequested, setPubRequested] = useState<Ipublication[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      setPubRequested(Publications);
  }, []);

  console.log(pubRequested);

`;

  return ()
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`${process.env.URL}/api/publication`);

  return {
    props: data
  };
};

export default PublicationsHome;
```

So, the logic is quite simple, i'm gettin data by using getStaticProps, that is server side rendering, but i want to use SWR hook, so i'm using initialData so i can use it, and, the las thing is, i'm using useEffect and i want to pass Publications data from swr to my useState, the problem is that, Publications data is slow enough to not be able to pass the data.

**As you can see**, i have a console.log() and it returns me undefined

What can i do about it, i need that data in my useState, any ideas ?

*Thanks people*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wait for the data to load.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(data){
      setPubRequested(Publications);
    }
  }, [data]);
```